# Is there a way of making text that is unreadable at high brightness but becomes readable as brightness is reduced?

Tags: text, transparency, contrast

I am looking for a way of displaying text that is unreadable at high brightness but becomes readable as brightness is reduced on a screen/monitor.

Any clues?
Thanks

Comment: On what medium, van we alter the circumstances?

Comment: The primary platform for this project would be laptops/computers. Any insights regarding the topic would be great. Thanks @joojaa

Answer (score 1):

Very light grey on white may work. The key is low contrast so that when the brightest is cranked it blows out all the subtle colors.

Comment: It has proven to work slightly but in a very subtle way. Not quite substantial enough to make the text readable but more experimentation is needed. Thanks for the help! @DA01

Comment: @sambrown1198 I think that's about the best you'll get. The brightness is only that...brightness. It doesn't directly change contrast which is what you need

Answer (score 0):

If we look at first principles of the physics. Contrast reduction simply means less difference between colors. Offhand it is really hard to imagine a direct situation where this would work out.

However there might be a way to overlap the monitor with a screen that could do it.

Comment: I like your thinking with the overlapping screen, something I will look into. 

I have been experimenting with the contrasts between white and light grey, which has shown some improvements on the idea but not enough to become a substantial design. Thanks for the help! @joojaa

Answer (score 0):

Try pure white text on a pure black background, with a very thin condensed font, bold with small features (ideally a low x-height), with very tight kerning / tracking, and lots of space between lines.

With the screen mostly black, the readers' pupils will dilate. The edges of the white characters at high brightness will be less distinct due to increased glare and fuzzier focus from the eye letting in more light. With all the important details tight, it'll be harder to tell which character is which.

With brightness reduced, glare will reduce and the details will be more visible.

Related reading: [White text on black background](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/551/white-text-on-black-background)